# NodeJS / ExpressJS google analytics on page redirect

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, server-side, google-analytics-api

I have an app that is built in AngularJS on top of Node/Express/MongoDB. Outgoing links are first sent to a page at `/out/:item_id` which is then looked up, saved to my database and redirected to the correct external URL.

For now the code looks like:

```
exports.outgoing = function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;

    db.products.find({"_id": mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function (err, record) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Lookup Error: " + err);
        } else{
            console.log("Redirecting to " + record[0].infoLink)
            res.redirect(record[0].infoLink);
        }
    });
};
```

I'd like to be able to track this event on Google Analytics so I can track what the outgoing link is, but don't know how, as the default code attaches itself to the `window` which isn't really feasible here. Very new to server side stuff.

Comment: Do you want to track the actual link (`record[0].infoLink`) or your internal link `/out/:item_id`?

Comment: @TheHippo I want to track `record[0].infoLink`.